# How do I check for sql errors in PDO in JSON format?

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, pdo

I am using luracast restler for making REST APIs. I am trying to update user using post method. But my sql is not executed and i dont know how to look for sql errors in json format.

My API code is

```
<?php
class User
{
public $dp;

function __construct()
{
    $this->dp = new DB_PDO_MySQL();
}
function post($request_data = NULL)
{

    $response = array();
    if(array_key_exists('user_id', $request_data)){
        $response = $this->dp->updateUser($request_data);
    }else{

        $response = $this->dp->signUp($request_data);
    }
    return $response;

 }

}
```

and updateUser function in MySQL is as

```
function updateUser($postData){

    $response = "";
    $data = array();
    if($this->checkToken($postData['token'])){
        $sql = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM phpclassifieds_acc_users WHERE username =      :username');
        $sql->execute(array(':username' =>  $postData['username']));
        if($sql->rowCount()>0)
        {
           return $this->response(0,'','The Username ('.$postData[username].') is already in use');
        }

        $sql = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM phpclassifieds_acc_users WHERE email = :email');
        $sql->execute(array(':email' =>  $postData['email']));
        if($sql->rowCount()>0)
        {
           return $this->response(0,'','The Email Address ('.$postData[email].') is already in use');

        }
        $sql = "UPDATE phpclassifieds_acc_users SET
                type = :type,
                username = :username,
                password = :password,
                name = :name,
                address =:address,
                address2 =:address2,
                address_city = :address_city,
                city =:city,
                zipcode =:zipcode,
                state =:state,
                email =:email,
                newsletter =:newsletter
                WHERE user_id = :user_id";



                try{



                $stmt =$this->db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':type',$postData['type'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':username',$postData['username'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':password',$postData['password'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':name',$postData['name'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':address',$postData['address'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':address2',$postData['address2'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':address_city',$postData['address_city'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':city',$postData['city'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':zipcode',$postData['zipcode'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':state',$postData['state'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':email',$postData['email'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam(':user_id',$postData['user_id'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $var = $stmt->execute();
               } 
              catch(PDOException $e) {
                $err[] = var_dump($e->getMessage());

               echo json_encode($err);


                }

        if($var){

            $response = "Update Successfully done..";
            $sqlSelect = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM phpclassifieds_acc_users WHERE user_id = :user_id');
            $sqlSelect->execute(array(':user_id'=>$postData['user_id']));
            $data =  $this->id2int($sqlSelect->fetch());
        }else{
            $response = "Update is unsuccessful ..";
        }
        return $this->response(1,$data,$response);
    }
  }
```

The problem is when i dont use try catch the output is "Update unsucessful...." and when i use try catch i get "Unexpected token s".

Comment: where you are getting this `Unexpected token s`

Comment: it looks like you are missing the $stmt->bindParam for ':newsletter'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code is strange

```
$err[] = var_dump($e->getMessage());
echo json_encode($err);
```

It's weird to encode a var_dump into json, you should just be able to do:

```
$err[] = $e->getMessage();
echo json_encode($err);
```

or you can get the error from `errorInfo()`

```
echo json_encode($this->db->errorInfo());
```

---

Don't forget to bind the newsletter parameter:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':newsletter',$postData['newsletter'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
```